# Unable to execute subplot command for multiple graphs in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

this is my dataframe(named census):

```
    Ethnicity   USA All CA All  USA Children    CA Children
0   Black       0.12    0.05            0.14    0.05
1   Hispanic    0.18    0.38            0.24    0.50
2   White       0.62    0.39            0.52    0.29
3   Other       0.08    0.18            0.10    0.16
```

im trying to show parallel plots, but cant seem to find where i am going wrong
this is my code:

```
error im facing:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c9aa8709606a> in <module>
----> 1 fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)
      2 plt.tight_layout()
      3 ax1 = census[['USA All','CA All','Ethnicity']]
      4 ax1.plot.barh()
      5 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)
plt.tight_layout()
ax1 = census[['USA All','CA All','Ethnicity']]
ax1.plot.barh()

ax2 = census[['USA All','CA Children','Ethnicity']]
ax2.plot.barh()

ax3 = census[['USA Children','CA Children','Ethnicity']]
ax3.plot.barh()

ax4 = census[['USA All','USA Children','Ethnicity']]
ax4.plot.barh()

plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error factor is drawing more than one subplot, you need to match its matrix structure with the specification of the ax Relate each graph to an ax. The graphs you have created are based on my estimates and may not be what you intended.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, [[ax1,ax2],[ax3,ax4]] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12,9))

df1 = census[['Ethnicity','USA All','CA All']]
df1.plot(kind='barh', x='Ethnicity', y=['USA All','CA All'],ax=ax1)

df2 = census[['Ethnicity','USA All','CA Children']]
ax2 = df2.plot(kind='barh', x='Ethnicity', y=['USA All','CA Children'], ax=ax2)

df3 = census[['Ethnicity','USA Children','CA Children']]
ax3 = df3.plot(kind='barh', x='Ethnicity', y=['USA Children','CA Children'], ax=ax3)

df4 = census[['Ethnicity','USA All','USA Children']]
ax4 = df4.plot(kind='barh', x='Ethnicity', y=['USA All','USA Children'], ax=ax4)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]